# GuzzleHttp has a different headers in production and localhost

Tags: php, json, laravel, http-get, guzzle

I use a function to fetch some data from instagram, I make a get request with GuzzleHttp, on localhost it works beautifully, but when going up to production the response to get is different, not being a valid json, I've tried everything but without success anyone already went through this situation?

I defined the header correctly, in localhost the content-type is sent as "application / json" but in production it is sent as "text / html; charset = utf-8"

My guzzle Request:

```
$requestContent = [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
    ];


    $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
    $url = 'https://www.instagram.com/feup_porto/?__a=1';


    try {

        $response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
            'headers' => ['content-type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'applicatipon/json', 'charset' => 'utf-8']
        ]);
    } catch (GuzzleException $exception) {
        dd($exception);
    }

    dd($response);
```

$response in Localhost

[image]

$response in production:

[image]

$response->getBody() in localhost:

[image]

$response->getBody()->getContents() in production:

[image]

Comment: what you are showing in the second image doesn't look like a response, have your tried using exception handling, like using $response->getBody()->getContents() only if response code is 200

Comment: Thanks, but the response code is 200 in both cases

Comment: have you tried copying that html & loading it using a new file with .html extension might give some hints whats inside the html, you can post the rendered html here as screenshot as well

Comment: Thanks, I already edited the question with the html print that is sent in the response on the production server

Comment: though I am not sure, check the headers what headers are send by guzzle when on server & on localhost, also you can try adding user-agent header with Mozilla values `user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36`, not know if it will work or not

Comment: not work, but thank u any way

Comment: Can you share the response **body** for both requests?

Comment: Hi Nico, I added these prints in the question

Comment: As requested in the very first command: please use `$response->getBody()->getContents()`, not anything else

Comment: thanku, already changed in the question, in localhost the json is returned, in production it is returned html,